# jQuery syntax error - wont close script

Tags: jquery

Dreamweaver won't let me close my jQuery for some reason, It appears to be a syntax error.

The concept is to have a series of buttons with unique id's ie. #apr for april each loading a html file into a div (called gigs).

I've tried moving stuff around, adding and taking away `;` 's and `});` 's but can't seem to find a solution

here's my code so far;

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){;

        $("#apr").click(function(){
$("#gigs").load('gigs/april13.html');

        $("#may").click(function(){
$("#gigs").load('gigs/may13.html');

        $("#jun").click(function(){
$("#gigs").load('gigs/may13.html');

        $("#jul").click(function(){
$("#gigs").load('gigs/may13.html');

        $("#aug").click(function(){
$("#gigs").load('gigs/may13.html');

        $("#sep").click(function(){
$("#gigs").load('gigs/may13.html');

        $("#oct").click(function(){
$("#gigs").load('gigs/may13.html');

        $("#nov").click(function(){
$("#gigs").load('gigs/may13.html');

        $("#dec").click(function(){
$("#gigs").load('gigs/may13.html');
    });
});
});
</script>
```

The error seems to always fall on the last line before I close the script tag. All input would be appreciated as I'm new to jQuery

Edit: All links are to may as I haven't created the html files for the rest of the year yet :)

Comment: You're missing a `});` after pretty much every `.click(function () {`.

Comment: In response to your edit... you really need to consider a better way of doing this. A listener on just individual days of may should probably just be a datepicker field that evaluates on change.

Comment: @KaiQing I'm afraid I'm not that proficient yet, I would love that sort of fuctionality but even this is confusing me

Comment: you need a code editor that will tell you if your syntax is wonky...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fiddle with the solution.  This tool is great, and it will help you see where braces or parens are closed as well.  http://jsfiddle.net/mNZeT/

The issue is that you weren't closing each of your "load" calls.  Those should appear like this:

```
 $("#apr").click(function(){
        $("#gigs").load('gigs/april13.html')**})**;
```

Comment: thank you for your help, I'm uploading now to see if it works :), Edit: Absolutley flawless, Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 4):

Here's your problem

```
$(document).ready(function(){; <---- WHAT IS THAT SEMI COLON DOING THERE???
```

And close the rest of your functions:

```
$("#apr").click(function(){
    $("#gigs").load('gigs/april13.html');
}); <--- CLOSE THESE
```

You also have one too many `});` at the end. Remove one.

Answer (score 0):

You are not closing your clicks events:

```
$("#apr").click(function(){
$("#gigs").load('gigs/april13.html');
```

Should be:

```
$("#apr").click(function(){
    $("#gigs").load('gigs/april13.html');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem with you missing curly braces, parentheses and semicolons at the end of each click function - give this a try:

```
   <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#apr").click(function(){
    $("#gigs").load('gigs/april13.html');
});

$("#may").click(function(){
    $("#gigs").load('gigs/may13.html');
});

$("#jun").click(function(){
    $("#gigs").load('gigs/may13.html');

$("#jul").click(function(){
    $("#gigs").load('gigs/may13.html');
});

$("#aug").click(function(){
     $("#gigs").load('gigs/may13.html');
});
$("#sep").click(function(){
    $("#gigs").load('gigs/may13.html');
});
$("#oct").click(function(){
    $("#gigs").load('gigs/may13.html');
});
$("#nov").click(function(){
    $("#gigs").load('gigs/may13.html');
});
$("#dec").click(function(){
    $("#gigs").load('gigs/may13.html');
});
});
</script>
```